# List all root categories in magento2

Tags: magento2

How do you list all root categories (and their child categories) in a template file (phtml) in magento2?

I'm running 0.74.0-beta5.

Answer (score 3):

The following code should give you a list of all the root categories; you can change the depth to get children of children and change the rootId if you only want a specific tree.

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryManagementInterface $obj */
$obj = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryManagementInterface');

$rootId = 1;
$depth = 1;

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryTreeInterface $items */
$items = $obj->getTree($rootId, $depth);

foreach($items->getChildrenData() as $item) {
    print_r($item->debug());
}
```

As always; you shouldn't use the object manager directly and should instead inject the `CategoryManagementInterface` into your code it via the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Mage:: class in Magento2. Answer provided by @Nasir is not for Magento2, but Magento1.
In Magento2 you may use Repositories, check this:

```
Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryManagement
```

or

```
Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository
```